# Uploading WAR file to websphere 8.5 give the error "The EAR file could be corrupt and/or incomplete." and "Failed to mark"

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-8

Uploading a WAR file to websphere 8.5 give the following error, what could be causing this and what action should be taken?

```
The EAR file could be corrupt and/or incomplete. Make sure that the application is at a compatible Java(TM) Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE) level for the current version of WebSphere(R) Application Server.

com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.SaveFailureException: Failed to mark [ WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xmi ] in [ xyz.war ] [Root exception is org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.SaveFailureException: Failed to mark [ WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xmi ] in [ xyz.war ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can occur due to syntax errors in the xmi files. In this case a quote was missing from an attribute, causing the error.